# AttributeError: type object ' ' has no attribute ' '

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributeerror

I  already asked something similar on the site, but I can't get over this error. The code that I'm using is:

```
class Enemy:
# Base class to create all future enemies
def __init__(self, name, hp, dmg, desc):
    self.name = name  # Enemy name
    self.hp = hp  # Enemy hp
    self.dmg = dmg  # Enemy damage
    self.desc = desc  # Enemy description (Will make sense later)

def is_alive(self):
    return self.hp > 0
```

The code above is used to define all future enemies, as I stated on with #. Then, I created three enemies for testing, as my game will generate random encounters from a list. However, I'm only going to list one because the error happens with any enemy:

```
class Goblin(Enemy):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(name = "Goblin",
                     hp = 40,
                     dmg = 33,
                     desc = "An ordinary goblin runs in your direction!")
```

Then, as the enemies do, the rooms of the dungeon also have a template class and a list for random purposes, but as I did before, I will only list one because it's the one that is causing errors to me:

```
class Room:
# Template to define all future rooms
    def __init__(self, intro):
        self.intro = intro

class VsRoom(Room):
# Room with an enemy
    duelist = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.duelist = duelist = random.choice(Enemy_List)
        super().__init__(intro = "There's an enemy here! \n%s" %(duelist.desc))
```

And then there's the "def" to run the game (currently just for testing):

```
def print_room():
#  Tells the player the type of room they are
    print("You enter the next room...")
    print()
    gen_room = random.choice(Rooms)()  # ("Rooms" is a list) 
    print(gen_room.intro)
    if gen_room == VsRoom:
        combat()  # No need to list the combat() definition, I think.
```

But when I run, I get this:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Goblin' has no attribute 'desc'
```

I know that `AttributeError` is quite easy to find here, but it seems that none of the existing questions suits me. If anybody knows why the code fails, please tell me.

Comment: Look at your indentation.

Comment: Looks like `Enemy_List` contains `Goblin` classes instead of objects. Where is `Enemy_List` created? Frankly, the upper and lowercase mixture between variables and classes seems like crying out for such errors.

Comment: @dhke Yes, `Enemy_List` contains the `Goblin` class, that's probably what is causing errors. How could I fix this?

Comment: @fuzzything44 Oops. It was correct on my code, but I messed up when writing the question. It's correct now.

Comment: @Bernardozomer: If `Enemy_List` contains types of enemies (enemy `class`es), not specific enemies (enemy instances), you need to take the class you selected and call it to construct a specific enemy. If it's supposed to contain specific enemies, you need to construct the individual enemies, not just insert the class object. Either way, we can't give specific suggestions when you show none of the code that initializes `Enemy_List`.

Comment: The code of `Enemy_List` is simply `Enemy_List = [Goblin, GiantSpider, Ogre]`. Note that `GiantSpider` and `Ogre` are made exactly as `Goblin`, just with different values for `name`, `hp`, `dmg`, and `desc`.

Comment: Well .. 1) `Enemy_List` contains classes. 2) The attributes of the base class `Enemy` are instance attributes, the class doesn't have them. 3) Consequently `duelist` contains a class and that one doesn't have a `desc`. Either change `EnemyList` to contain actual objects or instantiate the actual enemies before accessing them.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do this. If you could provide further help, it would help me a lot.